# Multiple SSH private keys, possible?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

Is it possible to have multiple SSH key in a single client, and let ssh choose the right one automatically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can have different private keys in different files and specify all of them in `~/.ssh/config` using separate `IdentityFile` values (or using `-i` option while running `ssh`). They would be tried in sequence (checkout `man 5 ssh_config`).

If you are using `ssh-agent` though, you might have to tell the agent about the multiple keys you have using `ssh-add`.

Comment: Note that if one account has multiple valid keys (e.g. because you use `authorized_keys` to run specific commands instead of a shell), you may have to use the `IdentitiesOnly yes` option to make sure `ssh-agent` doesn't use the wrong one. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52092/863

Answer (score 10):

Yes:

> ```
> -i identity_file
> ```
>
> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public
>      key authentication is read.  The default is `~/.ssh/identity` for
>      protocol version 1, and `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` and
>      `~/.ssh/id_rsa` for protocol version 2.  Identity files may also be
>      specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is
>      possible to have multiple `-i` options (and multiple identities
>      specified in configuration files).  ssh will also try to load
>      certificate information from the filename obtained by appending
>      `-cert.pub` to identity filenames.

Just add `-i` for each identity, or use several `IdentityFile` lines in you `.ssh/config`.