# How to use ssh-agent with multiple (valid) keys and yet choose which one to use?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Let's say there are two keys `A` and `B`, both of which are valid for `user@host` public key authentication. Since `authorized_keys` is configured for different behaviour depending on the key, `~/.ssh/config` on the client uses something like

```
Host A.host
    HostName host
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/A
Host B.host
    HostName host
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/B
```

That works fine. However, the moment I use `ssh-agent` and add both keys `A` and `B` (e.g. in order to enter their passphrases at login instead of when I call the respective `ssh A.host` or `ssh B.host`), the connection will always use the same id for both virtual hosts. Is there any way to specify *which* stored key `ssh` should use from `ssh-agent` without having to remove the other key?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/401737/choose-identity-from-ssh-agent-by-file-name

Comment: Thank you @jasonwryan, this leads me to believe I have to add `IdentitiesOnly yes`. That's also [the answer](http://superuser.com/a/272613/35237) to another question which weirdly ended up on SU... I'll try this tomorrow

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [answered elsewhere](https://superuser.com/a/272613/35237), the trick is adding the option `IdentitiesOnly yes` which makes sure that *only* the configured keys will be used even if others are available from the agent.